# Delete photo from google photos API

Tags: picasa, google-photos

Is it possible to delete any photo stored in google photos programmatically? I've seen [picasa web API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol#Photos) but can't see that it's possible to delete files via API.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking the same thing.

I'm not an active developer myself, so take this advice with a grain of salt, but looking a the help pages:

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started
https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/

... nothing jumps out at me that would suggest that you can delete a photo via the API.

This is annoying, because one of the glaringly obvious features missing from the otherwise-excellent Google Photos service is the ability to auto-detect, and optionally delete, duplicate photos. For various legacy reasons, I've literally 1000's of duplicates in my collection which would take me days to identify and delete manually.

So hopefully in the not too distant future, Google Photos API will allow deletion, and/or Google Photos will add this into the core feature set.

Answer (score 1):

The API does not provide this feature.

You can upvote the issue in Google's bug tracker by starring this item https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109759781

Comment: I'm going to save someone a click, the issue was resolved as won't fix infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

The API does not provide the feature, however if you do need to delete all or some of your photos, there is https://github.com/mrishab/google-photos-delete-tool

It runs in your browser however, in the JS console :(

Comment: This needs to be upvoted 100 times. I get the sneaking suspicion that the fact that Google left a batch delete out of their photos API is intentional. I have been paying for storage for a few years now because I couldn't figure out how to delete 1,000 photos that were taking up all the space. **THIS** is exactly what I needed to fix this problem. Sorry Google, but I'm keeping that $2.99 per month from now on!!